# Installing neo4j in openshift

Tags: neo4j, openshift

While I run **sh neo4j console** inside the **/neo4j/versions/2.1/neo4j-2.1/bin**. I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Max 16384 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
2015-11-29 11:58:24.427+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.configuration.ConversionException: 'org.neo4j.server.webserver.port' doesn't map to an Integer object
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getInteger(AbstractConfiguration.java:845)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getInt(AbstractConfiguration.java:819)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.webServerPort(Bootstrapper.java:239)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConversionException: Could not convert "${OPENSHIFT_NEO4J_DB_PORT}" to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertyConverter.toNumber(PropertyConverter.java:413)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertyConverter.toInteger(PropertyConverter.java:260)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getInteger(AbstractConfiguration.java:841)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""${OPENSHIFT_NEO4J_DB_PORT}""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertyConverter.toNumber(PropertyConverter.java:409)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you put in a shell variable `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""${OPENSHIFT_NEO4J_DB_PORT}""`
 in Neo4j's `neo4j-server.properties` which is not supported.

Try to modify your config script to rather replace the port inline in the config file, like this:

`sed -i -e "s|org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=.*|org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=${OPENSHIFT_NEO4J_DB_PORT}|g" $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j-server.properties`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you've hit the max files limit.  This article talks about it in relation to Neo4j:

[Neo4j WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924596/neo4j-warning-max-1024-open-files-allowed-minimum-of-40-000-recommended-see-t)

Specifically you would up the numbers in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  You may need to restart.

This seems to be possible on OpenShift:

https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-increase-the-open-file-limit-on-as7-instance