# Error when importing csv using import tool

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I'm trying to load a graph with two nodes (Autor,Paper) and a relation with the import tool, right now I have this two files, which, as far as I understand, they must be:

authors.csv:
:Author(Autor)  :Adscription(Autor)  :PMID(Paper)
Author1  Department of Hematology.  31207293

Papers.csv
:PMID(Paper)  :PaperName(Paper)  :AuthorList(Autor)
31207293  A huge paper name  Author1,Author2,

These files are stored in /var/lib/neo4j/import

With this in mind, I run the following code

```
sudo neo4j-admin import --database=graph.db --id-type=STRING --mode=csv --delimiter="  " --nodes :Autor:Paper="authors.csv,Papers.csv"
```

but I got

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 []
usage: neo4j-admin import [--mode=csv] [--database=<name>]
                      [--additional-config=<config-file-path>]
                      [--report-file=<filename>]
                      [--nodes[:Label1:Label2]=<"file1,file2,...">]
                      [--relationships[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]=<"file1,file2,...">]
```

Right now, I'm only attempting to load the nodes Paper and Author, I'm able to do this in the browser by means of

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM   "file:///authors.csv" AS row
MERGE ( c:Autor{ Name:row.Autor  , Adscription: row.Adscription, PMID=row.PMID } )
```

but the time taken by doing so, is long.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is probably not affecting you, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924596/neo4j-warning-max-1024-open-files-allowed-minimum-of-40-000-recommended-see-t) for more info.

If you are importing large amounts of data, the reason why your Cypher is taking so long is because of `MERGE`. If you know that the `authors.csv` contains a unique entry for each author, then you do not need to do a `MERGE` since it will never match to an existing node.

Try switching `MERGE` to `CREATE`. It should be much faster.